# Remove colour codes from output of an executable in powershell

Tags: powershell

The following script removes all the colour codes from an output of an executable:

```
gulp test | ForEach-Object -Process {$_ -replace "$([char]27)\[[0-9]*m", ""}
```

But it has got (at least) two problems:

- Some characters are outputted with wrong encoding (it outputs "├╝" instead of "ü")
- Error output and standard output get out of order (the lines are out of order compared to the output without replacement)

How do I get rid of the colour codes in an output of an executable without waiting for the process to finish?

---

Output of `gulp test`:

[image]

Output of the above script:

[image]

Comment: To address your second bullet point: PowerShell output streams are independent of each other and PowerShell does not guarantee output order across streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to strip color codes after the fact, instruct `gulp` not to produce colored output to begin with:

```
gulp test --no-color
```

This should make your two other problems go away as well, but just to address them briefly:

- Use `gulp test 2>&1` to merge stderr and stdout output, which would send the lines in proper sequence to `ForEach-Object` - note that stderr lines will be of type `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` (which is helpful for determining what stream a particular line came from).
- To fix the problem with the misinterpreted characters, first set `[console]::OutputEncoding` to match the output character encoding used by `gulp`, which I presume is UTF-8 (`[console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::Utf8`)